# Tutorial "Writing a Simple Service and Client", i modified the wrong file, what can i do?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I wish to learn ros and I started by doing the tutorials available on ros.org.

But in the "Writing a Simple Service and Client" tutorial, when it say to modify the file `~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt`. I modified the secure file that is in `~/catkin_ws/src` using `sudo gedit CMakeLists`. Before that, it worked but now I have a mistake when I do `catkin_make`.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:94 (message): add_message_files() directory not found: /home/audensiel/catkin_ws/src/msg

Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_message_files)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/audensiel/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/audensiel/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". Invoking "cmake" failed
```

When I remove all files and folders and I restart at the beginning (the tutorials), and i created `mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src` ... The file I modified previously is always the same. I think this is my problem, so if someone can give me the contents of this file or tell me how to retrieve the original.

Thank for your help.

William

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256485/tutorial-%22writing-a-simple-service-and-client%22,-i-modified-the-wrong-file,-what-can-i-do?/) by [w.fradin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29616/w.fradin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q227161 (but replace `indigo` with`kinetic`, obviously).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [w.fradin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29616/w.fradin/) on 2017-03-08**:
Thank a lot, problem solved !